# How to get full file path on Strapi custom upload provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-management-system, strapi

I have a custom upload provider on my Strapi project that is in charge of uploading the assets of the Strapi Media Library to an S3 bucket.
The problem is that if I create a folder in the Media Library I don't have access to that folder name inside my custom provider.
Strapi sends a `folderPath` endpoint but it's just numbers instead of my folders name (e.g. 1/2).

I tried creating a folder in the Strapi Media Library and uploading a file inside it.
Then I logged the file on my custom upload provider but I don't see nothing referring to the folder name.

To create my provider I followed this [guide provided by Strapi](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/providers#creating-providers)

Here is a log of the file Strapi sends:

```
name: 'image.jpeg',
alternativeText: undefined,
caption: undefined,
folder: '1',
folderPath: '/1',
hash: 'image_782bf9a508',
ext: '.jpeg',
mime: 'image/jpeg',
size: 397.61,
tmpWorkingDirectory: '/var/folders/3y/m7m67qms2t5f5jsd46ncm33c0000gn/T/strapi-upload-KmFZVe',
getStream: [Function (anonymous)],
width: 2048,
height: 1024,
stream: ReadStream {...}
```

Any idea on how I can get the full file path?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? We cannot upload large files through Strapi (hosted on Heroku) to Cloudinary. Heroke crashes our app. But when we go to upload direct in Cloudinary, it does not show our folder structure. Nor the file when we upload it. So we're stuck, we can't upload large files.

Comment: Hi @LaurenceCope ! 
I found [this post](https://punits.dev/blog/customizing-the-strapi-upload-plugin/) and ended up doing what's described there. Hope it helps!